# Length of array too long Java

Tags: java

I need to initialize a long[] in java of length k+1. However k is of type long, and can be up to length 10^12. Because of this, the program is throwing an incompatible types error.

```java
Error: java: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int
```

What should I do?

Edit:
I can't cast to int **because k can be of length 10^12**

Comment: Cast to `int` first.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't cast to `int`? If you are in control of `k`, please declare it is an int. You're probably never going to have an array that requires a long to represent its length

Comment: Please read my edits. k can be of length 10^12, which is too long for an int

Comment: Do you really expect your array to have length 1000000000000 though? Could you provide some more context about why `k` can be so big?

Comment: It is from USACO so yes

Comment: Can you tell us what this array and `k` are for? Perhaps there's another way to approach it

Comment: USACO  obviously doesn't define you have to use an array of length 10^12. May be there is other way to solve this.

Comment: Such array would requre 8 * 10^12 bytes of storage which is over 7450 GB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Java.  You simply cannot have an array larger than ~2 billion entries (i.e., maximum positive value of an **int**) for a single dimension. The [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) forbids it.  The dimension expression must have an **int** value.

Therefore, there's no point in trying to have a **long** value for size; you can't.

Furthermore, of course, as already noted in comments, you're talking about requiring approximately 8TB of address space, so there's a secondary reason why this isn't going to work out well.

So, to answer the specific question "what should I do?", you have a choice.

1. Accept the limitation of about 2 billion entries, or
2. Radically redesign your data and algorithms to cope with the large data you're expecting to process.

Since you say this is USACO, I'd guess the point is to have you figure out something for the second of the above two options.